# How to read registry keys to output in powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, registry

I need to get returned back all the keys in the registry tree:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\

There, manually, I found v4 v4.0 and CDF.

I need to be able to do this en masse for some automation tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$reg = Get-ChildItem -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\" -Recurse
$reg.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this incorporating @dno answer:

```
(dir "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\" -Rec)|select -eXp Name
```

Comment: It was hard to choose because both asnwers are useful. I went for the one that was easier for me to understand... but at the same time yours is more efficient. ANyway, I cant even upvote yet because of my rep. Thank you for your answer.